# Gridview not populating from access db with parameter query - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I have a page where I am trying to populate a gridview (gvClockings) on a button click based upon a selection in a dropdownlist (cbLocation) and a from/to date entered into textboxes from a calendarextender (txtFrom and txtTo).

I have tested the SQL statement and it gets the expected results if I run it in Access (and I have similar SQL working fine with a gridview on a different form in this solution), however on this form no matter what I select in the 3 controls, the gridview will not display any records.

cbLocation is populated in Page_Load as below:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = cbLocation
        Dim ir As ListItem = New ListItem
        Dim ee As ListItem = New ListItem
        ir.Text = "IR Room"
        ir.Value = "IR Room"
        ee.Text = "Employee Exit"
        ee.Value = "Employee Exit"
        ddl.Items.Add(ir)
        ddl.Items.Add(ee)
    End If
```

I then have the below code to get the data and populate the gridview:

```
    Private Sub GetClockings(ByVal LLName As String, ByVal FromDate As String, ByVal ToDate As String)

    Dim conclock As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; DATA SOURCE=\\xxx.xx.xxx.xx\AccuFace\pspcms.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxx;")
    Dim daClocking As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT efrLog.LFirstName, efrLog.LLastName, efrLog.LDepartment, efrLog.LDate, efrLog.LTime, efrLog.LType, efrLog.LLName FROM efrLog WHERE (((efrLog.LDate) Between [@FROMDATE] And [@TODATE]) AND ((efrLog.LLName)=[@LLName])) ORDER BY efrLog.LDepartment, efrLog.LTime"
    Dim selectCMD As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(selectSQL, conclock)
    daClocking.SelectCommand = selectCMD

    selectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LLName", LLName)
    selectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FROMDATE", FromDate)
    selectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TODATE", ToDate)

    Dim dsClockings As DataSet = New DataSet
    daClocking.Fill(dsClockings, "efrLog")

    If dsClockings.Tables("efrLog").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        gvClockings.DataSource = dsClockings.Tables("efrLog")
        gvClockings.DataBind()
    Else
        lblNotFound.Text = "No clockings found for this location"
        lblNotFound.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code is called from Button_click as below:

```
Dim LLName As String
    Dim FromDate As String = txtFrom.Text
    Dim ToDate As String = txtTo.Text


    If cbLocation.SelectedValue = "IR Room" Then
        LLName = "IR Room"
        GetClockings(LLName, FromDate, ToDate)
    End If

    If cbLocation.SelectedValue = "Employee Exit" Then
        LLName = "Employee Exit"
        GetClockings(LLName, FromDate, ToDate)
    End If

    lblLocation.Text = "Clocking report for " & cbLocation.SelectedValue.ToString() & " generated on " & Date.Now
    lblLocation.Visible = True
```

I have debugged locally as far as I can (I am using an access db on a remote server from IIS so get connection string/permission-related errors when trying to fill the dataset when running locally. I know it's a horrible setup but it's what I have been given to work with and I don't know how to debug remotely) and as far as I can see, the parameters appear to be receiving the correct values (see below)

[image: Screen shot]

The data I am requesting from the db definitely exists so I'm completely stuck as to why the gridview isn't populating. Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OleDb provider doesn't recognize parameters by their name, but by their position.
You add the parameter values in the wrong order as they appear in the command string.
Probably this cause an error or doesn't return anything...

Try to respect the order of definition of the parameters in the command text in this way

```
Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT .....FROM ... WHERE " & _
                          "(((efrLog.LDate) Between [@FROMDATE] And [@TODATE]) AND " & _
                          "((efrLog.LLName)=[@LLName])) " & _
                          "ORDER BY efrLog.LDepartment, efrLog.LTime"

selectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FROMDATE", FromDate)
selectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TODATE", ToDate)
selectCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LLName", LLName)
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, worked perfectly. I wasn't aware that this was the case. Thanks for your help